# Getting an error after injecting IAmazonS3 into command handler (MediatR) in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, .net-6.0

I have registered IAmazonS3 into Programs DI as follows :-

```
var awsOptions = builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
awsOptions.Credentials = new 
    BasicAWSCredentials(builder.Configuration["S3FileUploadSettings:AccessKeyID"], 
    builder.Configuration["S3FileUploadSettings:SecretAccessKey"]);
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

I have injected IAmazonS3 into command handler as follows:-

```
 private readonly IRepository<Beneficiaries> _repository;
 private readonly IMapper _mapper;
 private readonly IAmazonS3 _s3Client;

 public CreateBeneficiariesCommandHandler(IRepository<Beneficiaries> repository,
        IAmazonS3 s3Client,
        IMapper mapper
        )
 {
    _repository = repository;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _s3Client = s3Client;
 }
```

I have registered the MediatR as follows:-

```
 public static class ApplicationServiceRegistration
 {
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationService(this IServiceCollection 
    services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

        return services;
    }
 }
```

I got the following error:-

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Beneficiary.Commands.CreateBeneficiariesCommand,System.Boolean]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.

If I initialized AmazonS3Client into constructor then its working without any issue:

```
    public CreateBeneficiariesCommandHandler(IRepository<Beneficiaries> repository,
        IAmazonS3 s3Client,
        IMapper mapper
        )
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_s3FileUploadSettings.Value.AccessKeyID, _s3FileUploadSettings.Value.SecretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1);
    }
```

Comment: And removing `IAmazonS3 s3Client` from ctor parameters makes it work?

Comment: Yes its working if I not inject IAmazonS3 s3Client and initialize inside ctor